# Reading incorrect values?

Tags: java, android

I have the follow class, extending Thread.
The idea is to extract the date inside the thread, and everything goes well, until the sometime when the received data is larger than a few kilobytes, and then i am starting to reading complete incorrect data.

```
public class ThreadBooksPositions extends Thread
{

    public ThreadBooksPositions()
    {
    }
    ..
    // default constructors

    public void run()
    {
        InputStream       iSS           = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection    = null;
        Integer sectionsDescriptorSize1 = 0;
        Integer sectionsDescriptorSize2 = 0;

        try
        {

            URL url = new URL( "192.168.1.4/bookstore.asp?getbooks" );
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
            connection.connect();

            iSS = connection.getInputStream();

            BufferedInputStream bIS = new BufferedInputStream( iSS );

            if( bIS.available() > 4 )
            {
                Float   lat           = 0F;
                Float   lng           = 0F;

                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                byte[] bf;
                try
                {
                    bf = new byte[ bIS.available() ];

                    while ( bIS.read( bf ) != -1) 
                        out.write( bf ); //copy streams

                    out.flush();
                }
                catch ( IOException e )
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } //you can configure the buffer size

                byte[] bO = out.toByteArray();

                if( out != null )
                {
                    try
                    {
                        out.close();
                    }
                    catch ( IOException e )
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.wrap( bO );

                sectionsDescriptorSize1 = data.getInt();
                sectionsDescriptorSize2 = data.getInt();

                ByteBuffer sectionData;

                try
                {
                    if( sectionsDescriptorSize1 > 0 )
                    {
                        byte[] bAS0 = new byte[ sectionsDescriptorSize1 ];
                        data.get( bAS0 );
                    }

                    if( sectionsDescriptorSize2 > 1 )
                    {
                        // trajectory
                        byte[] bAS1 = new byte[ sectionsDescriptorSize2 ];
                        data.get( bAS1, 0, sectionsDescriptorSize2 );

                        sectionData = ByteBuffer.wrap( bAS1 );

                        Boolean readingFailed = true;

                        if( sectionData != null )
                        {
                            while( sectionData.available() > 1 )
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    readingFailed = false;
                                    lat           = sectionData.getFloat();      // 4
                                    lng           = sectionData.getFloat();      // 4

                                }
                                catch( Exception e )
                                {
                                    readingFailed = true;
                                }

                                try
                                {
                                    if( readingFailed == false )
                                    {
                                        addBookStorePosition( lat, lng );
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception e) 
                                {
                                }
                            }
                        }

                }
                catch( Error e )
                {
                }
            }
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            if( iSS != null )
            {
                try
                {
                    iSS.close();
                }
                catch( IOException e )
                {

                }           
            }

            if( connection != null )
            {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

- What might cause reading of incorrect data ?

Comment: Have you debugged it ?

Comment: Your code is difficult to read because everything is inside one method. It is a good idea to try to split the code inside run() to different methods. BTW, I think that you had better migrate this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @nakosspy Code Review is for reviewing code that actually works, not fixing code that doesn't work. Please don't tell people to go to other sites if you don't know what that other site is for.

Comment: @svick I missed that. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.
Seems like **.available()** is causing the issue, especially in a threads.